# Unknown column 'Bob' in 'field list'... php or mysql problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a curious problem that I hope is something stupid I overlooked.

I am getting an error that usually occurs when there is a missing column in a mysql table, or  a misspelled php variable: "Unknown column 'Bob' in 'field list'"...

Except 'Bob' is not the name of a column, its the VALUE I am trying to assign to the row. Why would php be confusing the two??

Here is my php function that I believe is the location of the error:

```
function recordGuest($id,$fname,$lname,$dinner){
    $conn = connect("wedding");
    $guest_query = "INSERT INTO guest (fname,lname,person_id)
                    VALUES (".$fname.",".$lname.",".$id.");";
    mysql_query($guest_query,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $guest_id_query = "SELECT id FROM guest WHERE person_id = ".$id.";";
    $guest_id_result = mysql_query($guest_id_query,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $guest_id = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($guest_id_result)){
        $guest_id = $row["id"];
    }

    $guest_dinner_query = " INSERT INTO guest_dinner (dinner_id,guest_id)
                            VALUES (".$dinner.",".$guest_id.");";
    mysql_query($guest_dinner_query,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Here is the php code that processes the form and executes the above function:

```
<?php
include("functions.php");

$code = $_POST["code"];
$type = $_POST["type"];
$people = getPeople($code);
$ids = $people["ids"];
$email= "";

for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++){
    $response = $_POST["response_".$i];
    $dinner = $_POST["dinner_".$i];
    recordResponse($ids[$i],$response);
    if($dinner != "null"){
        recordDinner($ids[$i],$dinner);
    }
    if($type == 3){
        $guest_responses = $_POST["guest_response_".$i];
        $guest_fname = $_POST["guest_fname_".$i];
        $guest_lname = $_POST["guest_lname_".$i];
        $guest_dinner_response = $_POST["guest_dinner_response_".$i];
        if($guest_dinner_response != "null"){
            recordGuest($ids[$i],$guest_fname,$guest_lname,$guest_dinner_response);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Heres what my "guest" mysql table looks like:

```
guest
    id int auto inc (primary key)
    fname varchar
    lname varchar
    person_id int
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: Did you try printing to generated SQL?

Comment: Hmm, would the quickest way to fix the vulnerabilities be to use mysql_real_escape_string()?  Does this only apply to string entries into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose the string in single quotes i.e. 'Bob' before trying to insert the string values

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try to enclose in sigle quotes like this :

```
VALUES ('".$fname."','".$lname etc
```

But better yet you should never insert stuff in the database that way, it open the risk of SQL injection and other bad stuff

unless you are using some draconian php version you can use PDO and use statement. Like in this example i nimbly stole from php.net

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```